# Paths in an Intellij Spring-project

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, intellij-13

So I am currently working on a Spring-project in Intellij. In my JSP-view I have both JQuery, Bootstrap and some local css/js-files.

When I work on the pure HTML in WEBSTORM the paths are easy to interpreter as they just are relative. As far as I understand the paths in Spring are defined in a XML-file and everything goes from there.

My **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml has this:**

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

And my files are organized like this:

- WEB-INF

  - css

    - bootstrap.css
    - login.css
  - js

    - All js files.js
  - pages

    - login.jsp
    - menu.jsp

How do i find the path? Have google like a hero and tried a lot but the files are *not found* Are there other files that rules over the path-hierarchy?:(:(

**Example:**

- `<script src="relative-path/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="relative-path/css/login.css">`

Comment: `css/js/..` are public resources, you shouldn't put them into `WEB-INF` folder

Comment: @Jaiwo99 But where do you recommend to put it? And how do I link it properly?

Comment: just put it in you webroot folder

Comment: hmm.. i will post a answer for you..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using maven:

- src/main
- java
- resources
- webapp

  - static

    - css
    - js
    - ...

Then the config..

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
```

then you can use `/css/main.css`, something like this to access your resources in jsp

But there are different options out there, I will suggest you to read the [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: Thanks, it helped :)